# Same function not giving same result after reload

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, function, each

So basically, my page is a shop so the content is generated with php shortcode as it follows :

```
<?php get_header(); ?>
<div id="main-content">
    <div id="page-content">
        <?php
            echo do_shortcode('[products limit="20" columns="4" category="t-shirt"]');
        ?>
    </div>
</div>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
<script>$(document).ready(linebreak)</script>
```

So it gives me a basic page like this, where my content is a list of elements :

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<div id="main-content">
    <div id="page-content">
        <ul class="my-list">
          <li class="my-element">
             <img>
             <h2>A title</h2>
          </li>
          <li class="my-element">
             <img>
             <h2>A title</h2>
          </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
<footer></footer>
</body>
</html>
<script>$(document).ready(linebreak)</script>
```

Acutally there is more than 20 li but you can see how my page looks like. I'm using the linebreak jquery function to check if my h2 title is having a line break cause I don't want it. If there is a linebreak, it is just keeping the 20 first characters and adding "..." at the end. It's working pretty well exept that there one or to h2 that are not always changed depending on my reloads. They do have a linebreak but when I reload my page several times, sometimes the function is changing them and sometimes it's not. It's only one or two specific h2 and always the sames. Why is my function not giving the same results each time I run my page ?

In case it can help, here is the function in my script.js that is included in the header :

```
function linebreak(){
    $("#main-content #page-content .woocommerce ul li h2").each(function(index){
        var lheight = Math.round(parseFloat($("#main-content #page-content ul li h2").css("line-height")));
        var title = $(this).text().trim().substring(0, 100).split("").slice(0, 21).join("") + "...";
        if ($(this).height() > lheight){
            $(this).html(title);
        }
    });
};
```

Comment: This `each()` is not running since you don't have an element with the class `woocommerce`.

Comment: I actually have one, just forgot it in the code here to simplify :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have an image of what you want? Would it not be easier to use CSS to manage titles that are too long?

The following code will automatically put an ellipsis if the title is too long, provided you set your width for the h2 element.

E.g.

```
h2 {
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help ! This totally amazing I had no idea css could do this ! The only problem is that it's not working with a width that is set in percentage. I still can convert my percentage in px with jquery so not a big deal !

Comment: Hm, interesting. Hard to say what could be happening without seeing a sample of your code.

Answer (score 0):

your script should be in the head part of document, so you need to find where`<?php get_header(); ?>` is generated. It is usually `header.php`

Comment: I'm using <script>$(document).ready(linebreak)</script> to call my script so why isn't it already waiting for the dom to be loaded ?

Comment: Have you tried ? Because the way an html document renders imposes this way. the head is parsed and processed first and then the body, if your script is in the footer part of the body, then it will be called only after the body is almost rendered which too late, for your case.

Answer (score 0):

You have to wait for the dom to be fully loaded

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    linebreak();
});
```

You can also check the header.php or footer.php to delete the code If your theme structure is simple

Comment: As i'm using <script>$(document).ready(linebreak)</script> to call my script, isn't it enough to wait for the dom ?

Comment: your h2 tag loaded by any javascript ? you cal also setTimeout(function () {},1000); for more wait . but it is not clearly solation . @Yuniru

Comment: Nope, all those li and their content are generated by the php echo, that's why I don't understand why my code seems not to wait for the dom to be ready

Comment: jQuery is just Javascript and JavaScript will be executed when encountered. because most jQuery code requires the document to be ready but the code attaching the event handler is certainly executed before the document is ready (otherwise it wouldn't be able to handle the document ready event). plz put jquery code in footer  and before </body> tag .@Yuniru